# Swipe between ViewController with Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I'm currently trying to connect different ViewControllers by swipe left but,The my code not work for me. I added Swipe gesture recognizer to the ViewController in stroyboard file
This my code

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeLeftGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;


       }

 -(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
if (touches == 2)
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //Add view controller here
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can do this manually, many people have built tools to help you do this. I recommend [RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers). Easy to set up, easy to use.

No more thinking about `UISwipeBetweenViewControllers`!